# How to prevent EntityManager.persist from committing to the db until manual flush call and not requiring @Transactional?

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, entitymanager

I am a bit confused about how Hibernate handles some things. I have a repository class in which i have a method that uses `persist` from **EntityManager** so it gets added to the managed state and persistence context. I then have a separate method with an `@Transactional` annotation to only call `flush` to manually commit everything currently in the **EntityManager**.

I do this because i am working with very large data sets, and already have to iterate over them a few times completely or partially before i get to store them, so i want to save iterations by *"adding them to the EntityManager"* while im already iterating over them and they are fully build, so i dont have to later iterate over the full list again in my repository class to call `persist` on each entity.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class DataRepository {
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    private int totalAmountOfCachedData = 0;

    @Inject
    public DataRepository(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
        // This line does not change anything, with or without the same result
        this.entityManager.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);
    }

    public int getTotalAmountOfCachedData() {
        return totalAmountOfCachedData;
    }

    public void add(Data data) {
        setReferences(data);
        entityManager.persist(data);
        totalAmountOfCachedData++;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void commitCurrentDataToDb() {
        entityManager.flush();
        totalAmountOfCachedData = 0;
    }

    private void setReferences(Data data) {
        //... running a few EntityManager.getReference here
    }
}
```

My understanding was that `persist` does not actually save the entity to the database, only when `flush` is called. Also, as far as i understand `@Transactional` wraps an automatic transaction with commit around the method, which i don't want for the prior one. The problem is: i am getting an exception when using my method `add()`, asking about adding a transaction. But if i add one, that would auto commit them to the db on every call, right?

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Transaction is not active, consider adding @Transactional to your method to automatically activate one.
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.session.TransactionScopedSession.persist(TransactionScopedSession.java:142)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionLazyDelegator.persist(SessionLazyDelegator.java:241)
        at org.hibernate.Session_5b93bee577ae2f8d76647de04cfab36afbf52958_Synthetic_ClientProxy.persist(Unknown Source)
        at com.test.entity.repository.DataRepository.add(DataRepository.java:36)
```

Also, i tried setting the flush mode for the **EntityManager** to *"COMMIT"* instead of *"AUTO"* but it doesn't make a difference. How can i have the `add()` method add the entities to the **EntityManager** without executing inserts, and only do so on the separate call with `commitCurrentDataToDb()`?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood your question: you would like to populate sets of data, and then flush that data occasionally from different user requests.

This leads to extended persistence context... Which was a thing in 2007 and in fully serverside applications, like JSF. And this is not what people usually do in spring or in any other stateless microservices world now.

What I can see - you are trying to mix service layer (application SPI) and persistence layer (application implementation).

What I would suggest for you to reorganize your code: introduce a stateful service.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class DataService {

   private final DataRepository repository; 

   private List<Data> currentDataSet;

   private ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

   @Inject
   public DataService(DataRepository dataRepository) {
      this.repository = repository;
      this.currentDataSet = new LinkedList<>();
   }

   public void add(Data data) {
       lock.lock();
       try {
          this.currentDataSet.add(data);
       } finally {
          lock.unlock();
       }
   }

   @Transactional
   public void flush() {
      lock.lock();

      final List<Data> dataToPersist;

      try {
         dataToPersist = new ArrayList<>(this.currentDataSet);
         dataToPersist.forEach(repository::save);
         dataToPersist.flush();
         this.currentDataSet = new LinkedList<>();
      } finally {
         lock.unlock()
      }
    }
}
```

And your DataRepository should implement 2 methods:

```
save(Data data) {
   setReferences(data);
   entityManager.perist(data);
}

flush() {
   entityManager.flush();
}
```

With this - you are operating with a `DataService`, and persistence layer is somewhere hidden from client of `DataService`.

But this kind of writing would make your application not horizontally scalable.  Then it would be best if you considered writing your data in the `DataService` to some shared in-memory storage, like Hazelcast or Redis instead of the in-current-jvm-memory `currentDataSet` list. And with this, you would achieve scalability.

And one more hint -> even though it is a good promise to have the same data in persistence and in SPI and in API - in practice, it works well for primitive use cases, for something more serious you should have separate data models for API, service and persistence layers and corresponding mappings. Yes, this is EE Java - and it pays out in long run. As a first start, I would suggest having only 2: API (shared with service) and Persistence layer data models.